# npm: exec in context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I would like to exec what can be executed by scripts in npm.

For example I have a vue-press installed and I would like to exec `vuepress eject`. In my scripts I can see `vuepress` is accessible, but I don't have a script for `eject`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vuepress dev docs",
    "build": "vuepress build docs"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "vuepress": "^1.3.1",
    "@vuepress/plugin-back-to-top": "^1.3.1",
    "@vuepress/plugin-medium-zoom": "^1.3.1"
  }
```

So I could create a script for one use or use whatever command `npm exec`. I am looking for the latter solution.

Comment: Sure, `"eject": "vuepress eject"` run with `npm run eject`. I'm not sure I understand the question exactly though

Comment: @AluanHaddad I don't want to add something in my `package.json`. Just execute `npm` with the same context it has in scripts. Obviously I can do `vuepress ...` in a script but not from the CLI as vue press is locally installed

Comment: I see what you're saying, unless you add the local bin to your path you're not going to experience the desired behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the docs it states the following about [executables](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/folders.html#executables):

<sub>**Note:** Bold emphasis added by me.</sub>

> When in global mode, executables are linked into `{prefix}/bin` on Unix, or directly into `{prefix}` on Windows.
>
> **When in local mode, executables are linked into `./node_modules/.bin` so that they can be made available to scripts run through npm.** (For example, so that a test runner will be in the path when you run `npm test`.)

So, given your requirement you can:

1. `cd` to your project directory.
2. Then run the following command:

   ```
   ./node_modules/.bin/vuepress eject
   ```